# How do I get TinyMCE working in a jQuery dialog on firefox?

Tags: jquery, tinymce, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-dialog

I need to get a tinymce editor working in a jquery dialog. In normal circumstances the tinymce editor will not be active and usable in an invisible dialog. It is required re-initialize the tinymce control when the dialog becomes visible. (based on http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=12338)

The solution proposed is to call the following tinymce command where appriopriate `tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',false,'txt_notesone')` and `tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl',false,'txt_notesone')`

I've added these to the `create` and `open` event handlers of the jquery dialog. This works fine in IE and Chrome but doesn't seem to work in Firefox (14).

You can find the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kfBNg/6/

Any ideas?

Comment: oh tiny MCE and dialogs. I have wasted so much of my life getting them to play nice.

have you tried destroying the dialog on close? that solved some of my problems.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't solve the problem. I guess destroying the dialog would solve the issue on a second opening of the dialog but tinymce is inactive even on the first open. I find it weird that it only affects firefox. Normally that's the browser that gives me the least problems :)

Comment: which version of tinyMCE are you using? I ran into this with 3.4.2 or so, I had to upgrade to 3.4.9.   something they did in firefox 12 or 13 broke it.

Comment: @Patricia Thanks for the suggestion. We currently use the 3.5 version. I tried with 2 different tinyMCE versions (3.4.9 and the latest in 3.5) but it didn't change anything. I also tried an older version of Firefox (10) but in that version the dialog didn't even open.

Comment: is there more to your dialogs then just the text editor?   have you tried creating a new element for your dialog, instead of using something in the dom already? then you can initialize and destroy everything each time.